# How do I create multiple definition boxes in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, definition

I wanted to create a particular slide in beamer. Please find below the pic for the same.
[image]

How do I do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the formating for ONE of your blocks already in place, this should do it:

```
   \begin{frame}
     \begin{block}{Title 1}
       Description of title 1
     \end{block}
     \begin{block}{Title 2}
       Description of title 2
     \end{block}
     \begin{block}{Title 3}
       Description of title 3
     \end{block}
     \begin{block}{Title 4}
       Description of title 4
     \end{block}
    \end{frame}
```

Comment: It works in a way. I was looking for a format as shown in the picture.